# Importing remote Angular2 Components

Tags: angular, components

Can anyone point me to documentation that explains how to import remote custom stand alone components into a new project? Our goal is to have separate teams work on individual components that get consumed by a container application. From all that I have read this should be doable, yet I cannot find any online examples.

Comment: Have you found a way to get this done?

Comment: I did some research on this too, only way possible right now is to publish your module on npm and then install that package in your application, the remote team then needs to republish the changes and then consumer can run update command to get the new build.